# Extract numeral from a set of links in python

Tags: python, regex

I have this array which contains these links:

```
https://www.example.com/category/brand_listing/soap-bodywash-shampoo-and-conditioner/1106
https://www.example.com/category/brand_listing/soap-bodywash-shampoo-and-conditioner/1106
https://www.example.com/category/brand_listing/face-care-beauty-and-makeup/1098
https://www.example.com/category/brand_listing/face-care-beauty-and-makeup/1098
https://www.example.com/category/brand_listing/deo-talc-and-wipes/1097
https://www.example.com/category/brand_listing/deo-talc-and-wipes/1097
https://www.example.com/category/brand_listing/grocery-and-gourmet/1120
https://www.example.com/category/brand_listing/grocery-and-gourmet/1120
https://www.example.com/category/brand_listing/health-drinks/1117
https://www.example.com/category/brand_listing/health-drinks/1117
https://www.example.com/category/brand_listing/oral-and-dental-care/1104
https://www.example.com/category/brand_listing/oral-and-dental-care/1104
```

I want to extract the last 4 digits in these urls

```
1106
1098
1097
1120
1117
1104
```

I am using python.

What is the easiest way of doing this?
is regex the way to go?

Comment: `str.split("/")[-1]` ?

Comment: Any specific reason that the URLs are duplicated but the extracted data example is not? `/(?:\/)(\d+)$/gm` will do the trick but if you want uniques only then you need to leverage Python.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
x=['https://www.example.com/category/brand_listing/soap-bodywash-shampoo-and-conditioner/1106',
'https://www.example.com/category/brand_listing/soap-bodywash-shampoo-and-conditioner/1106']
[i[-4:] for i in x]
```

---

Considering the specific position of the target, regex is not an efficient way.

Comment: str.split("/")[-1] this works!
[i[-4:] for i in x] this doesn't.

Comment: @IonAag Did you notice how `x` is constructed?